# Migrate from JAX-RS @Path to Spring MVC @RequestMapping using regex

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jax-rs, request-mapping

I'm trying to migrate code from Jax-Rs (jersey implementation) to a Spring MVC entry point:

jax-rs:

```
@GET
@Path("{bundle}/bundle{min: (-min)*}.{extension: js|css}")
public Response getBundle(@PathParam("bundle") String bundle, @PathParam("min") String min, @PathParam("extension") String extension)
```

Spring MVC:

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, path = "{bundle}/bundle{min:(-min)?}{extension:\\.(js|css)?}")
public void getBundle(@PathVariable String bundle, @PathVariable String min, @PathVariable String extension)
```

According to [Spring MVC documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex), i can use regex for `@RequestMapping`. The syntax is similar to jaxrs but the entrypoint doesn't work (404 Not Found).

Example of value for the entrypoint: `http://localhost:8080/foo/bundle-min.css`

I've found a solution with `@RequestMapping(method = GET, path = "{bundle}/bundle**")` but i have to parse the string to catch my needed parameter values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex seems fine but replace those *capturing groups* with *non-capturing groups*, like following:

```
{bundle}/bundle{min:(?:-min)?}{extension:\.(?:js|css)?}
```

With this regex, if you fire a request to `foo/bundle-min.css`, the `bundle` would be `foo`, the `min` would be `-min` and the `extension` would be `.css`.